# Custom login in angular 5 to authenticate with AzureAD

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, openid-connect

I have created a nodejs Web API for my backend, and my client application is written in Angular 5, as part of the requirements they want me to create a login page inside this app asking for email and password, I've been looking for an example where they try to do the same thing I am doing but I've been unlucky. I tried `angular-oauth2-oidc` library for doing this but I received a CORS error. Could someone provide a guide for doing this?

I've seen that moodle web app did this but is in PHP how I could implement this?

Comment: You actually don't want to do this. One of the reasons OIDC and OAuth2 exist is so that the end-user doesn't have to give it's credentials to your app. For angular apps, you should use the implicit flow which involves redirects. The `oidc-client` lib also has the ability to use an iframe though I have never used it. If you still want your own login form you could use the [Resource Owner Password Credentials grant](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)

Comment: You are right I don't, but my boss was asking for this, then I told him the same thing as you said, and that managed to convince him. xd